# Problema con TweenMax en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto y no me funcionan la animaciones con la librería TweenMax, no se por que razón,espero vuestra ayuda.A continuacion os dejo la parte del código que produce el error.

Este es el .html

```
<div id="header"class="page-header"><h1>titulo a animar</h1>
```

este es el .js

```
    window.onload = function () {
            var header = document.getElementById("header");
            TweenLite.to(header, 1, {left:"632px"});
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!Saludos!

Comment: Es un poco dificil ayudarte si no nos dices, al menos, qué error te da. ¿No hace nada? ¿La consola suelta algún tipo de error?

Comment: No da ningún error ni en consola ni en navegador, simplemente no inicia la animación.Podria ser un problema en la importación de librerías no?
Pero lo miré y creo que lo tengo bien, lo he probado ahora mediante cdn tambien y nada....

Comment: No sé cual puede ser el error. Si fuera por problemas en la importación, al cargar la página daría un error de que TweenLite es 'undefined'. De todas formas, no usaría window.onload. Si estás usando AngularJS, metería ese código en un bloque [run](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

Comment: te refieres a hacer una función en el controlador no?Pero si es así como arranco la animación sin botón ni nada sin onload?

Comment: No, me refiero a un bloque run() como en [este ejemplo](https://jsbin.com/kamote/edit?html,js,console,output). Si te fijas en la consola verás que se ejecuta lo primero sin necesidad de clicar ningún botón ni nada.

Comment: Entendido, voy a probarlo!Muchas gracias jjimenez!Ahora te cuento a ver que tal!

Comment: Ya lo probé y sigue igual, si hago un console.log en .run si me lo escribe, pero de la animación nada de nada.... no se que puede ser!!!!

Comment: @Alex00 Voy a editar los tags de tu pregunta, en vista que colocaste Angular 2, y esto es un problema de la primera versión, por ende no lo es lo mismo.

Comment: Sin problema Wilfredo, gracias!

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, lo he metido dentro de una directiva y funciona bien, no se que sería lo que estaba haciendo mal..
Muchas gracias de todas formas!Saludos!

Comment: Hola, ya que has encontrado la solución, sería muy bueno que  la compartas añadiendo una respuesta a tu pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Hecho! Publicada ;)

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución, no se que estaría haciendo mal, pero el caso es que funciona asi, lo meti todo dentro de una directiva en el modulo principal:

```
 .directive('animacion', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            TweenMax.to(element, 2, {
                ease: Bounce.easeOut,
                left:"632px"
            }, 1);
        }
    });
```

Y en el .html simplemente poner en el elemento que quiera animar la referencia:

```
<h1 animacion id="header">FlyingDonkey Store</h1>
```